# google script I get this error "Cannot find folder"

Tags: google-apps-script, directory

I'm using Google Code unchanged (except for the folder name) yet I get the error "Cannot find folder".

I've checked the spelling of the folder name and tried several different folders in "My Drive" but get the error on all of them. The exact same code works for my friend but not for me.

Here is the line of code:

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolder('My Docs');
```

Comment: Any chance the example script has no space in its folder name?

Comment: thx for the reply Daniel. My friend uses the following line and it works with no errors: var folder = DocsList.getFolder('My Photos'); which as you can see is just like mine. I set my folder structure just like his and copied the code from google examples just like he did. But I'll try changing the name of the folder just to check.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but do you actually have a folder called "My Docs" (with no quotes)? In attempting to replicate your error I made a "My Docs" folder at the top level of my Google Drive, and embedded your code in a function. It runs cleanly, but if I change the name of the folder in the code to something else, I get the same error you mentioned. Any chance you'd be willing to share/make public this code so we can directly take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the folder ID instead of the name.

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolderById("234asdfih-324asdf")
```

You can find your folder ID in the adressbar of your browser when you open the folder.
If you use the ID you can change the name of the folder later and it does not matter at all.

If you use the folder name watch that its case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a very similar but somehow different issue. Depending upon the folder name I include in CHECKLIST_FOLDER (and they are all valid), the command :

**`myFile.addToFolder(DocsList.getFolder(CHECKLIST_FOLDER));`**

returns (or not) the error message "Cannot find folder". Folders details and permissions are identical in all cases, no clear reason for failure.

In this case as well, Thomas' work around is working great, thanks !